# Why is mongo findById not working but match _id is?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm working on some code that transfers objects from a database on one server to a database on a different server, and I'm saving the object to the database with

```
db.collections.users.insertOne(userObj)
```

If the process gets interrupted, I need to check if the object has been saved already. I discovered that depending on how I search, I get different results!

```
User.findById(userObj._id).exec() // null
User.findOne({_id: userObj._id}).exec() // null
User.findOne({username: userObj.username}).exec() // m8
User.findById(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userObj._id)).exec() // null
db.collections.users.findOne({_id: userObj._id}) // m8
db.collections.users.findOne({_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userObj._id)}) // null
db.collections.users.findOne({username: userObj.username}) // m8
```

I initially thought I was going mad, but... (see answer, also by me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...turns out it's possible to insert an object with a string instead of an ObjectID! And this will cause `findById(id)` and `findOne({_id: ObjectId(id)})` to fail.

When I added this line before saving...

```
userObj._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userObj._id)
```

...now all of those searches find the document! **\o/**